# driver is not loading in wince 6.0 issue

Tags: driver, windows-ce

I added my driver in wince 6.0 platform builder. It compiles sucessfully and added in nk.bin(i checked manully by open nk.bin in vs2005) also reg file contaning that driver enrty. I did below processure to add my driver.

1. Copy  driver code into  “$(_TARGETPLATROOT)\Files\MyDriver”
2. Add below line at  “*platform.bib*”

   MyDriver.dll      $(_TARGETPLATROOT)\Files\MyDriver\MyDriver.dll        NK SHK
3. Add below line at  “*platform.reg*”

   `#include "$(_TARGETPLATROOT)\Files\MyDriver\MyDriver.reg"`

But when I flash that, nk.bin. driver is not loaded on board. I checked with tool which help to check which driver loaded on board.
Does anyone have idea about that?

Answer (score 1):

We have no idea what is in mydriver.reg, so if there's a problem there, or the resulting platform.reg, then that could be an issue.

There are a few ways to diagnose this problem.  The first step would be to check `ce.bib` and `platform.reg` and make sure the expected entries are there.  If the driver or it's registry entries are not ending up in the OS, that would cause a problem.

If that looks good, then there are two steps you can take.

1. Build a Debug version of the OS, copy the debug version of `device.exe` into the `FLATRELEASEDIR` of a Release build and call `makeimg`.  This will give you a release build with a debug version of device.exe.  Boot up and look at the debug messages for when it attempts to load the driver and look at the report of the failure.
2. Create a simple application that calls `ActivateDevice` and look at the return value from it.  Outputting debug messages from the driver in `DllMain` and `XXX_Init` is usually helpful as well.